# If statement socket io mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

How could I check in this code if `userally` or `enemyally` doesnt exist and then just not send them. Should I make if statement and then make two more `emits` without user ally or without enemy ally or without both?

```
AllianceMember.findOne({username: user.username}).then((userally) => {
 AllianceMember.findOne({username: enemy.username}).then((enemyally) => {
      io.emit('fight-win', {
          username: user.username,
          useralliance: userally.ally_title,
          enemyalliance: enemyally.ally_title,
          enemyname: enemy.username,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are json objects you can set default values for them as empty objects.

```
AllianceMember.findOne({username: user.username}).then((userally = {}) => {
 AllianceMember.findOne({username: enemy.username}).then((enemyally = {}) => {
      io.emit('fight-win', {
          username: user.username,
          useralliance: userally.ally_title,
          enemyalliance: enemyally.ally_title,
          enemyname: enemy.username,
});
```